# Convert Sub Query to a Join

Tags: sql, mysql

Hi is it possible to convert this sub query to a join ?

```
SELECT staff_no
FROM doctor
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM patient
                  WHERE staff_no = consultant_no);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT  staff_no
FROM    doctor
LEFT JOIN
        patient
ON      staff_no = consultant_no
WHERE   consultant_no IS NULL
```

For this to be efficient, `consultant_no` should be indexed and declared as `NOT NULL`.

If it's not, pick any column that is declared as `NOT NULL` in patient and replace `consultant_no` with this column in your `WHERE` clause.

See this article in my blog for comparison of three methods to do this query in `MySQL`:

- [**`NOT IN` vs. `NOT EXISTS` vs. `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`: `MySQL`**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Answer (score 3):

```
   SELECT staff_no
     FROM doctor
LEFT JOIN patient
       ON staff_no = consultant_no
    WHERE consultant_no IS NULL
```